# Java generic return value: double casting

Tags: java, generics, casting

I'm very new to Java and specifically to writing generic code. My task is to write generic function that will return value of ID column of the `ResultSet` object.

Parent class has integer ID and child class has string ID (I know it's unusual to have string ID but data is quite specific)

So in parent class I ended up with function:

```
public <T> T getRowId(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
   return (T)((Long)rs.getLong(idCol));
}
```

and in child class I have a method that overwrites parent:

```
public <T> T getRowId(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
   return (T)(rs.getString(idCol));
}
```

And when I need to call this function I just do:

```
getRowId(rs)
```

My question is if doing double casting `(T)((Long)...)` is fine? And is there an easier way to implement this function that I'm not aware of?

Comment: No, this isn't fine. `T` can be anything - like `String`, for instance - and you can't cast `Long` to a `String`. You can't return a `long` (the result of `rs.getLong()` generically, unless you pass a `Function<Long, T>` to the method as well.

Comment: string ID seems like a more solid choice tbh. You don't need to do arithmetic with it any ways.

Comment: Why is the getRow() method generic and returns T, if the only correct concrete type of T is Long (resp String)? That code doesn't make sense, but we don't know enough about the context to explain how to fix it. What is the class containing this method? What is the responsibility of this method (and its class)?

Comment: So basically what I need to do is to overwrite method in child class so, that it will have different return type (String, not integer). Child will always return String, Parent will always return Integer. The only way to overwrite return type that I've found is using generic T @JBNizet

Comment: we don't know enough about the context to explain how to fix it. What is the class containing this method? What is the responsibility of this method (and its class)?

Comment: In this case, it shouldn't be a child class. You're trying to misuse the type system, but there are better ways to solve this problem.

Comment: It would make more sense to just use covariant return types instead of the generic method. http://ideone.com/dnFVjG As people have already pointed out, the generic method doesn't really much sense here.

Comment: Is it the case the the child class ID is guaranteed to be in fact always a valid integer or long value despite that the column type is declared as a String/(var)char in the DB? I.e. instead of 101 the DB stores "101" and things like "#101" , "first", "_1" are not considered valid IDs despite that they are valid strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments said, it does not make sense to cast to `T` when you know exactly that you are getting `Long` or `String`.

Here are 2 approaches you can take:

**Approach 1:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T getRowId(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    return (T)rs.getObject(1);
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
public interface RowMapper<T>{
    public T getRowId(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException;
}

public class ParentRowMapper implements RowMapper<Long>{

    public Long getRowId(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        return rs.getLong(1);
     }
}

public class ChildRowMapper implements RowMapper<String>{

    public String getRowId(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        return rs.getString(1);
     }
}
```

Comment: Please remove Approach 1. That is reckless, terrible advice. Unless you can justify that the cast will never fail (because of something you know that the compiler can't know), you shouldn't suppress the unchecked warning; if you can justify it, you should add the justification in a comment on the suppression. In this case, you can't guarantee safety.

Comment: I still would not discard first approach. You can never enforce contract and safety on compile time. There are cases that you need to assume that column value is of type `T`. This is same as calling `resultSet.getLong` on string column. You can always pass Class<T> into this method and do additional validation if you want to avoid `ClassCastException`.

Comment: I ended up with approach #2, thank you for the advice